# Customized iOS popup/alert

Tags: ios, uialertview

I wonder if there is an example code of a customized iOS popup/alert that has a "X" button on the top right corner. I found MTPopupWindow that does so but it only allows fixed message to show. I'd like to dynamic generate the message for the popup.

Answer (score 0):

You could present a view modally and have a custom button on the top right corner. The button type would be UIButtonTypeCustom. Create a delegate of the modal view to the main view (for receiving the action of the close button).

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look on [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) and maybe extend it to show a closing button on top.